# How to access public methods of the jQuery Smart Cart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using folloiwng jQuery library in my application. The plugin has provided two public methods as follow.

https://github.com/techlab/SmartCart/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.smartCart.js#L566

```
    // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    /* 
     * Public function to sumbit the cart
     */
    submit: function () {
        this._submitCart();
    },
    /* 
     * Public function to clear the cart
     */
    clear: function () {
        this._clearCart();
    }
```

I'm initilizing the cart as follows.

```
var cart = $('#smartcart').smartCart();
```

I want to know how can I call the clear() method. I have tried different ways, but it gives me undefined error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
// Initialize Smart Cart 
$('#smartcart').smartCart();

// Using public functions (clear and submit)
$('#smartcart').smartCart("clear");
$('#smartcart').smartCart("submit");

// Example: Clear cart when an external button click

//HTML
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-clear-cart" type="button">Clear cart</button>

//JavaScript
$("#btn-clear-cart").on("click", function() {
$('#smartcart').smartCart("clear");
return true;
});
```